# Django only serving a single static file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I just got started in Django a few days ago from Ruby and have only run into one really annoying problem that I just can't seem to figure out on my own. I've tried everything I can think of to no avail.
I am trying to serve up two static files, a custom CSS file (style.css) and a bootstrap.min.css file.
While this should be very easy as everybody keeps telling me, I must be staring at the outside of the box because I can't fix it. I would like to note, it does not work in both live (which I don't expect it too because I don't have a root set) or local environments. It currently will only serve up bootstrap.min.css
*EDIT:
When collectstatic is run, it passes through. I have set STATIC_ROOT to 'STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')*

**my settings file:**

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

My Main Template:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Django Boards{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Peralta" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>
```

My File Structure:

```
Main Project
     boards
     project1
     static
        css
          bootstrap.min.css (loads first files)
          style.css (wont load second file)
     templates
     manage.py
     db.sqlite3
```

Comment: Did you run the [`python manage.py collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#deployment) command?

Comment: I did, I get the error for STATIC_ROOT is not set. Even when I set my STATIC_ROOT to the same DIR as STATICFILES_DIR and run collectstatic I get the same problem

Comment: What are the file permissions on each css file?  If you try to load style.css directly in a browser, what happens?

Comment: Good thought, it loads properly though

Comment: Okay then, what happened that made you think it wasn't loading?

Comment: @ColtonVanBastelaere Well, that's surely a problem. You should edit your question including the definition of `STATIC_ROOT` and what `collectstatic` reports.

Comment: I put a test piece of CSS on my base.html template, just an h1 CSS tag and tried to make it red for a simple test to see if it is loading, h1 tag does not change

Comment: Bakuriu, I will but as of now it goes through fine

Comment: By default, many browsers will not reload css files on each page request, but will use a cached copy.  So if you edit your css and then reload the page, be sure to do a "full page reload" or  "hard refresh".  (A common shortcut for this is Ctrl-F5.)

Comment: Wow that is great, it is now working, I closed and reopened the browser and it didn't change, ctrl + f5 and I cleared the "Pycache" folder. Whichever fixed it im extremely glad for the simple fix. Thank you!